# Typescript array from map sorted by value?

Tags: typescript

I am trying convert a map into a sorted array. There are millions of solutions around, all of which result in one of many many many different errors.

I want to sort this:

```
public midiCcs: Map<string, ControllerInfo> = new Map<string, ControllerInfo>();
```

into an array of ControllerInfo ordered by ccMsb:

```
export class ControllerInfo {
    public name: string = "unassigned";
    public ccMsb: number = 0;
    public ccLsb: number = 0;
    public max: number = 127;
    public min: number = 0;

    constructor(jsonObject: any) {
        this.name = jsonObject.name;
        this.ccMsb = jsonObject.ccMsb;
        this.ccLsb = jsonObject.ccLsb;
        this.max = jsonObject.max;
        this.min = jsonObject.min;
    }

    public toString = () => {
        return `ControllerInfo ${this.name} ${this.min} to ${this.max} ccMsb ${this.ccMsb} ccLsb ${this.ccLsb}`
    }
}
```

Would greatly appreciated a way out of this minefield.

Comment: `[ ...midiCcs.values() ].sort((a, b) => a.ccMsb - b.ccMsb)` -- looks good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach with `sort()` (to sort `Map` by keys) and `values()` (to get values from `Map`).

```
class ControllerInfo {
    public name: string = "unassigned";
    public ccMsb: number = 0;
    public ccLsb: number = 0;
    public max: number = 127;
    public min: number = 0;

    constructor(jsonObject: any) {
        this.name = jsonObject.name;
        this.ccMsb = jsonObject.ccMsb;
        this.ccLsb = jsonObject.ccLsb;
        this.max = jsonObject.max;
        this.min = jsonObject.min;
    }

    public toString = () => {
        return `ControllerInfo ${this.name} ${this.min} to ${this.max} ccMsb ${this.ccMsb} ccLsb ${this.ccLsb}`
    }
}

const midiCcs: Map<string, ControllerInfo> = new Map<string, ControllerInfo>([
    ["C", new ControllerInfo({ name: "C" })],
    ["A", new ControllerInfo({ name: "A" })],
    ["B", new ControllerInfo({ name: "B" })]
]);

const notSortedArray: ControllerInfo[] = Array.from(midiCcs.values());

console.log(notSortedArray)

//shorter version in short()
//const sortedArray: ControllerInfo[] = Array.from(new Map(Array.from(midiCcs).sort()).values());

const sortedArray: ControllerInfo[] = Array.from(new Map(Array.from(midiCcs).sort(([key1], [key2]) => key1.localeCompare(key2))).values());

console.log(sortedArray)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7ALgJ3iEBTVBJRAZvNAN4BQ0l0ADgK4BGIAlsNImALZYBc0EaTRAHNoAXmgAiWuyhMhiLABMJAbgpU6jFtGDAAshHq9EtDvRxjoABjVUaDZq10AZQ8dPnUlm+sqbH0BxgAB7uZhbiAIwATADsthoO2hyCYZ7ear46SPyotMDI8KgAFABWEEgA8vSlWAW8YIgAngCUpFl2yAAWTBAAdOxcluVVNXXIA5xYCXaU3b19ugb0wxWI1bUFi-qGM7Pz-S6Gq6ObE0f0e509-UHBJ+tjW3dXVAd9KYgPG+MfgnsAXzIWX82kKAGUBMJLMU2qIAHztWZUVBYZC0VBfAAGCBQ6EwOHwRGgABISO9BlgAaTyTc-ohqYUae87tSlscye92fQ2cBXCtOXSLgCsVkgUCyMAcshAkxFExYMAILw9GBqAAeXKCIQAGjgSDQGGweEI8ER4gUAHdoKqNVrhHrcYaCSaiPDigBtLIeiSwCR6q36vFGwmm4okNhTXi+iTQAEtAC6Ou9EgAgv62FhrU78caifBw5GuNH03HE8m7D6AEIZwM5kOugsRynRmtlhNkBMtTJSxD8NjwZDgorIJSp1CoMBNXj1l35j0JyzjydNPoEdAcYopeWK-oANzAIFoWAgsO7wN7FWwfRA8CExUQg+HqFHimXU5awIA9F+IF0RxYe44BATBINAgh8P+L6wmQP6XjKFQvmOE5TjOBq5qGRALkuKGruu8CboGtrFO+eEblucoKkqLR9IhyBnn0B5HieZ49tKfAAW+uFocGc6mth4ikWu5FEWqJG4cJBEUTu1G0SOxSegA1lgTSREm0AespTTRF2YiIlpkQ3vAwCHlgCAcNQYCosUWnRC09mMYex6nvZbF9hgWBGfedHISuLRAA)

Comment: `[...midiCcs].sort()]`  makes no sense. It's a very roundabout way of sorting by key but also very error-prone way to do that. And most definitely doesn't sort anything (either values or entries) by `ccMsb`. Moreover, `new Map([...midiCcs].sort()).values()` is also a roundabout way of getting the values sorted by their key. If that's the intention then `Array.from(map).sort((key1], [key2]) => key1.localeCompare(key2)).map(([, value]) => value)` is 1. more correct 2. more direct.

Comment: Hmm I think it's no harm to use shortcut, but for maintenance, it's important for making the code readable, agreed with you on this.

Comment: *Why* sort the array of entries, *then create a map*, and then also *extract the values from the map* to turn them back into an array? What is the purpose of jumping through so many hoops?

Comment: Also, this is still only sorting by keys. Not, as the question has asked from the very beginning, property of the value.

Comment: I think I am creating my map incorrectly from the server response. midiChart.midiCcs.values() gives me an error "TypeError: midiChart.midiCcs.values is not a function" even though JSON.stringify(midiChart.midiCcs) looks correct.

Comment: @VLAZ `Array.from(midiCcs).sort()` is to convert the current map to an array for `sort` usage, but `values()` is only available in `Map`, so we need to convert it back to `Map`. From the final result `values()`, we can populate a new array for it which is the ultimate `Array.from`

Comment: @NickVu the array of entries that is being sorted *contains the values*. Converting *an array of key value pairs* to a map just to extract the values is exceptionally useless. And a waste of both memory and CPU.

Comment: If we don't use `Map`, we can try this approach `Array.from(midiCcs).sort(([key1], [key2]) => key1.localeCompare(key2)).map(x => x[1])`. Hmmm I don't think it can be different from `Map` conversion @VLAZ

Comment: Creating another objec, to get an iterator out of it, and create an array out of that iterator, is definitely different from *not* bothering with the map and just making an array directly. I don't even know how you can argue the opposite. Do you  believe a map takes no memory? No CPU cycles to create? Because it definitely does. And you're only using it to get information out you already have. And [I did already demonstrate the no-Map approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713552/typescript-array-from-map-sorted-by-value/73713744?noredirect=1#comment130167454_73713744)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to keep the `string` label. It could be something like this:

```
Array.from(midiCcs)
    .sort(([label1, item1], [label2, item2]) => item1.ccMsb - item2.ccMsb);
```